# MySQL Inner Join with No Rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that I normalized and the idea is to allow for a business to select zero or more marketing sequences, but the kicker is that a handful of marketing sequences are required (right now I have 4, but the list can grow). So what I've done is structured my tables as such:

```
sequence
+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| sequence_id | customer_type_id | title | description | required |
|     1       |        1         |  ...  |     ...     |   true   |
|     2       |        1         |  ...  |     ...     |   true   |
|     3       |        1         |  ...  |     ...     |   false  |
|     4       |        2         |  ...  |     ...     |   true   |
|     5       |        3         |  ...  |     ...     |   true   |
|     6       |        4         |  ...  |     ...     |   false  |
+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------+----------+

business_sequence
+----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| business_sequence_id | business_id | sequence_id |
+----------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

`customer_type_id` and `business_id` are foreign key fields that link to tables that describe the type of customer (customer, former customer, etc.) and the business's information (name, address, etc.) respectively.

The reason why I have the `required` column in my sequence table is so that if a business decides not to allow for any of the non-required sequences, then that business would not need a row. After all, there's no need to have duplicate rows in the business_sequence table if the only piece of data that  is different is the `business_id` field.

Now what I'm trying to do is get all the rows and all the fields from the sequence table where the business_id in the business_sequence table matches a parameterized value (say 1 for the example that I'm going to show in a second). The query that I tried to use is:

```
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM
    `sequence` AS s
  INNER JOIN `business_sequence` AS b ON b.`sequence_id` = s.`sequence_id`
WHERE
  b.`business_id` = 1 AND
  s.`required` = true;
```

But this returned no results if the business had no rows in the sequence table. What I expected it to do is return the 0 rows from the `b.business_id = 1` but I also expected it to return the 4 "required" rows (ids: 1, 2, 4, and 5)  from the `s.required = true`.

Whenever I took out the INNER JOIN statement and the business_id portion of the WHERE clause, it does in fact return the 4 "required" rows. This leads me to believe that in my original query, because there are no rows for that particular business_id in the `sequence` table it isn't returning anything.

With all of this being said, how do I accomplish retrieving the zero or more rows when the `business_id` field matches the parameterized value **and** retrieve all of the rows when the `required` field is true?

Comment: Your required field, what kind of data is it?

Comment: @RadamesE.HernandezD.L.R. - I set it up as a Boolean field in phpMyAdmin, but the data type automatically changed to tinyint(1).

Comment: Maybe you can change your condition s.`required` = true; to s.`required` = 1; and check it

Comment: @RadamesE.HernandezD.L.R. - It is the same result. Take a look at my second to last paragraph where I believe it is failing at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by performing a UNION as such:

```
SELECT * FROM `sequence` WHERE `required` = true
UNION
SELECT 
  s.*
FROM
  `sequence` AS s
  INNER JOIN `business_sequence` AS b ON b.`sequence_id` = s.`sequence_id`
WHERE
  b.`business_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using OR condition in stead of AND ?

```
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM
    `sequence` AS s
  INNER JOIN `business_sequence` AS b ON b.`sequence_id` = s.`sequence_id`
WHERE
  b.`business_id` = 1 OR
  s.`required` = true;
```

Comment: Read the second to last paragraph on why that would not work.

Comment: ?? have you tried that? the second to last paragraph talks about removing JOIN statement and business_id from where clause, while I'm suggesting you keep them both in place while replacing 'AND' with 'OR' in your where clause.

Comment: I did try it and it didn't work, but the reason it failed is still the same. I think it is because no rows are matched up on the INNER JOIN.

Comment: Then the only way I see is you will have to UNION the results of two queries... (1) that has a join and with both conditions in where clause with an AND... (2) that does not have a join and with just &#39;required = true&#39; in the where clause.

Comment: I found the solution through the UNION statement before you replied to this, and it was similar to what you suggested. I've posted the solution as an answer.